# Calculating average monthly rainfall from raster using shapefile

Tags: raster, r

I've been working with some raster data (19 years of precipitation data) and a shapefile. The raster extent represents a square-shaped area and the shapefile is within the extent of the raster.

[image]

I want to obtain the average monthly rainfall, I mean the average rainfall for each month for all the time series.

Each month has 19 relevant rasters (from the time series period) and I can get the average rainfall which results to be a single raster for each month but don't know how to get the areal average rainfall (a single value that represents the rainfall within the shapefile).

I loaded the rasters as single objects in R. The `raster` function `mean(r1, r2, r3)` gives a raster as output, I want a single value that represents only the area of study.

So far I've been working with **R** and was wondering if I can get that calculation using the `raster` package or any other package.

Comment: Define your extent equal to one of rectangle and run cell statistics on relevant rasters

Comment: Raster statistics on output

Comment: Have you read the rasters in? Are they a number of single-band raster objects or have you read them in as a multi-band stack object? Did you know you can just do `mean(r1,r2,r3)` to get the raster of cell-means of a number of rasters?

Comment: I know, thank you for answering. I added more details. The `mean()` function works for the entire extent of the raster and gives a raster as output. I need a single value representing the inside area of the shapefile.

Comment: `extract(stack(raster1, raster2, ...), polygon, fun= mean, na.rm= TRUE)` perhaps?

Comment: That nailed it! I added some info in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I managed to answer my own question.

I've been working these past days and the code shared by [Kazuhito](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/84455/kazuhito) in the comments:

```
extract(stack(raster1, raster2, ...), polygon, fun= mean, na.rm= TRUE)
```

happens to work perfectly and thereby is the answer I was looking for.

I just want to point out some details. Despite the code is very simple and straightforward, in order to convert a shapefile into a polygon I did this:

```
kis_stk = stack(raster1, raster2, ....)
rgdal::readOGR('directory-of-shapefile', stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
                sp::spTransform(CRS(projection(kis_stk[[1]]))) -> basin
extract(kis_stk, spPolygons(basin), fun= mean, na.rm= TRUE)
```

This worked with a *.shp* file I had in the *directory-of-shapefile* location.

Hope all this info helps someone.